# box-sizing border-box not working horizontally on bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

[image: box sizing]
![box sizing doesnt work on first object][1]

Im having trouble box sizing on bootstrap, listing is horizontally when it shrinks to the max, and the first div is bigger in height, it just messes everthing up, when the seconds is bigger it works perfectly.

[image: box sizing]
![box sizing works on the second object not first.][1]

I have tried giving the items: display inline, inline-block. Nothing seems to work. I tried giving box-sizing class but it just doesnt work.

I have been trying for hours now, I dont know what path to take to make it work.

Here is a live preview:
http://www.desarmaduriaipar.cl/bs_index.php

```
         <div class="box-sizing col-sm-3  col-xs-6">
            <div class="product-box">

                    <a title="alt" alt="alt" href="/desarmaduria/desarme/845/hyundai-accent-2012-2013-2014-2015-2016-2017">
                    <img src="http:www.desarmaduriaipar.cl/cars/thumbs/51501541613.jpg" width="100%" border="0">
                    <h3>Hyundai<br/>Accent 2012-2017</h3>
                    </a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

UPDATED:

This is the fix:
     .row.fix{
      display: flex,
      flex-wrap: wrap;
     }

Comment: Please post enough code in the question itself to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B updated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to inconsistent height of the box (.product-box), The solution would be to set min-height property for class product-box which is equal to the height of the highest .product-box element

```
.product-box{
    min-height : 200px;
}
```

Comment: I have made this code work before withouth boostrap, but with bootstrap it becomes a problem.

Comment: This is the fix my friend I had to go higher one div  .row.fix{ display: flex, flex-wrap: wrap; }